# php while loop will not increment database column

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, increment

I have a function like this:

```
function searchSingleUrlGraph($mysql){
    $query="SELECT * FROM `dailydata` WHERE `userid`='".$_SESSION['userdata']['userid']."' AND `url`='faboolis.com'";
    $HTML='[';
    $result=$mysql->query($query);
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            $HTML .= "[
                        ['".$row['date']."',".$row['fblikes']."],
                        ['".$row['date']."',".$row['fbshares']."],
                    ],";
        }
    $HTML .=']';
    return $HTML;
}
```

the result I want is this:

```
[[['Jun 4',224],['Jun 5',34],],[['Jun 4',220],['Jun 5',30],],];
```

but right now Im getting:

```
[[['Jun 4',224],['Jun 4',34],],[['Jun 5',220],['Jun 5',30],],];
```

I know there is an easy solution I'm just brain dead right now and its driving me crazy.

Comment: Are you trying to build a JSON array?  Am I missing something here, as what you want and what you are getting look the same to me.

Comment: No, im using this data to construct a graph with javascript.  I want the dates different.  look at the dates and you will see what I mean.

Comment: however it IS a JSON Array

Comment: so you should build a simple php array and then do json_encode($array)

Comment: Isn't your desired output going to be duplicates/redundant? `Jun 4, 224 fblikes` / `Jun 4, 224 fblikes` and `Jun 5, 34 fbshares` / `Jun 5, 30 fbshares`. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JohnnyKay  If you are going to construct a graph in javascript, then I would think have a JSON serialization would be ideal for passing the information to javascript.  I guess where I am going here is you could jsut build the array structure as desired in PHP and then `json_encode()` it so you don't have to deal with building the string yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to just use 2 while loops.

```
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    //process likes
}
$result->data_seek(0); //go back to the beginning.
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //process shares
}
```

Comment: I actually tried a variation of the $result->data_seek(0) and it worked fine.  Thanks.